# div within a div background of parent div not working on nested div

Tags: html, css

I have problem between two `div`s. `div#mainbody` which is parent `div` has a background and `div` 2 child `div` has its own background so `div` 2 floating out of the parent `div` but I want it to be inside parent `div`.

***HTML:***

```
<!-- parent div -->
<div id="mainbody">hi
   <div id="b1"></div> <div id="b2"></div> <!-- children divs -->

   <div id="main">
      <img src="images/fslam.png" id="fill" /><br/>
      <img src="images/register.png" id="register" /><br/>
      <img src="images/login.png" id="login" />
   </div>
</div>
```

***CSS:***

```
div[id=mainbody] {
   background-image: url(../images/img1300.png);
   box-shadow: 8px 8px 16px #000000;
}

div[id=main] {
   position: absolute;
   width:500px;
   height:375px;
   background-color:#FF6;
   z-index:1;
   background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,#81cbbc,#fcf59b 2%);
   -webkit-background-size:100% 40px;
}
```

Comment: As a note: You can use `#mainbody` instead of `div[id=mainbody]`. It's not only shorter it will also be faster.

Comment: i will keep it mind tx !!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/crYLK/

Comment: thanx i hope you can see the problem in result

Comment: @insertusernamehere Also, `#someid` is standard for all browsers... `[attribute=some]` is CSS3 feature and it won't be supported in older IE without some JavaScript magic...

Comment: @VukašinManojlović Actually it's a CSS 2.1 feature: [w3.org: 5.8 Attribute selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors). It will work down to IE7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `position: relative;` instead of `absolute`.

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/crYLK/2/)

```
#main {
    position:relative;
    width:500px;
    height:375px;
    background-color:#FF6;
    z-index:1;
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #81cbbc, #fcf59b 2%);
    -webkit-background-size:100% 40px;
}
```